# How large are the fictitious forces due to our orbit around the galactic center?

Tags: forces, estimation, centrifugal-force, milky-way

When we are in a non-intertial system, this creates fictitious forces. Some well-known fictitious forces are the centrifugal and coriolis forces. Those are caused by the Earth's spin around its axis.

However, we also move around the center of the Milky Way with a speed of about 247 km/s. How large is the fictitious force which this generates?

EDIT
It would also be interesting to know whether the forces are large enough to be measured by humans.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the centrifugal force?

Comment: Hi Riemann. Welcome to Phys.SE. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: The formula for the centrifugal force is $F=m\omega^{2}r$.

Comment: We have $\omega=2\pi/(240*10^6*3*10^7)=9*10^{-16}$

Comment: And $r=27000*9.46*10^{15}=3*10^{20}$

Comment: So the result is $2*10^{-10}$ Newton per kilogram.

Comment: Which is very small, as is the Coriolis force.